# How to close collapsible div when opening new one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set up collapsible divs. They work fine, but when I open another collapsible div, the opened ones wont close unless I manually close them one by one.

How can automatically make an opened collapsible div when opening a different one?

HTML

```
<html>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">BUTTON</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p style="padding: 20px 0;">CONTENT</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">BUTTON</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p style="padding: 20px 0;">CONTENT</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">BUTTON</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p style="padding: 20px 0;">CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</html>
```

JS

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please include your html. Something should be wrong with your ids or classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before opening a collapsed div, your code will have to close all open divs.

```
// toggle collapse of specified content
function toggleContent(content) {
  if (content.style.maxHeight) {
    content.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}

// collapse all open content
function collapseAllOpenContent() {
  const colls = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');
  for (const coll of colls) {
    if (coll.classList.contains('active')) {
      coll.classList.remove('active');
      toggleContent(coll.nextElementSibling);
    }
  }
}
```

Working example:

```js
// toggle collapse of specified content
function toggleContent(content) {
  if (content.style.maxHeight) {
    content.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}

// collapse all open content
function collapseAllOpenContent() {
  const colls = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');
  for (const coll of colls) {
    if (coll.classList.contains('active')) {
      coll.classList.remove('active');
      toggleContent(coll.nextElementSibling);
    }
  }
}

const colls = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');
for (const coll of colls) {
  coll.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {
      collapseAllOpenContent();
    }
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    toggleContent(this.nextElementSibling);
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #555;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">BUTTON</button>
<div class="content">
  <p style="padding: 20px 0;">CONTENT</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">BUTTON</button>
<div class="content">
  <p style="padding: 20px 0;">CONTENT</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">BUTTON</button>
<div class="content">
  <p style="padding: 20px 0;">CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I left off the bit that does the collapsing, fixed now. See the working example.

Comment: One last thing: with your example, the opened div cannot be closed anymore; it'll remain open. It'd be perfect if it could be closed back as it did before this addition

Comment: OK, it now allows manual closing of an open div. I also cleaned up the code a bit.

Comment: That is simply amazing! Once again, I wish I knew all this stuff. I'm not a developper at all, I just run my own website with basic html and css knowledge. So when I come up with this sort of difficulties, I get completely blocked at it... once in a while I get to solve it by my own, but as you saw this time I wasn't able. Thanks buddy, you've been very helpfull for me today and I really appreciate your time and patience :)

Comment: You've created what's called an accordion, which is a built-in feature of Bootstrap. You can save a lot of JavaScript coding by using Bootstrap. Here's an example accordion: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion and here's Bootstrap home page: https://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Thank you so much I'll take a look to it now :)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many concerns about this approach...

1. Separation of concers e.g separate styling vs template (CSS vs HTML). Move all the styles into a separate css file. Setting the styles also in JS instead of using a CSS class inside which you can add the styles that you want e.g maxHeight, padding, etc.
2. Not using semnatic HTML for your code.E.g. use details as a wrapper, use summary to serve as description for the wrapper, and use button to toggle the p content.
3. Adding multiple click events based on the length of the `document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible")` collection, which is not ok performance wise. You can add the event on the document.body, then verify if the clicked element is of a given type and has a given class/id.

But, at this moment, you don't even need JS anymore to do this kind of functionality. All you need to do is to use `details` and `summary` tags, which will behave in this accordion manner.

```
<details>
    <summary>Accordion item title 1</summary>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      content for the second item
    </div>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>Accordion item title 2</summary>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      content for the first item
    </div>
</details>
```